# How to write the bash scripts with automatic function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, automation

To save the bash as create_mysql.sh, we can create a database `magento` and a user `magento_user` with full privileges by `password`.

```
mysqlword="xyzzy"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword -e"CREATE DATABASE magento;"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword -e"use magento;"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword -e"CREATE USER magento_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword -e"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON magento.* TO magento_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword -e"FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword -e"exit"
```

How to rewrite the bash scripts to do the same task with postgresql, as an automatic script not interactive command in psql?

Comment: What did you try first? Where did you get stuck? Have you looked at any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the environment variable PGPASSWORD. In your example that would be

```
PGPASSWORD="xyzzy"
psql -U root -c 'CREATE DATABASE magento;'
```

On the command line you can put the environment variable definition before the command:

```
PGPASSWORD="xyyxxy" psql -U root -c 'CREATE DATABASE magento;'
```

or export the variable and then use it in subsequent commands

```
export PGPASSWORD="xxyyzzy"
psql -U root -c 'CREATE DATABASE magento;'
psql ...
```

Comment: A `.pgpass` file is generally preferable.

Comment: I agree @CraigRinger but I was trying to give an answer which is close in spirit to the MySQL code in the question.

Comment: I would also put the commands into a file and use the `-f` option to `psql`.